# Why is our Android Application unsupported by some devices

Tags: android, compatibility, google-play

Our Android application is not supported for some devices, and I can't figure out why.

For instance, the HUAWEI C8812. But it's a recent phone, running Android 4.0, so.. what's happening?

Below is the aapt dump of our APK, but I have a more general question: Google Play provides the list of all unsupported devices for a given APK. That's somewhat helpful, but why can't I have, for a specific unsupported device, a list of items that will tell me precisely why this device is unsupported (like `android.permission.CAMERA`. At least it would narrow my search.. ).

Any help appreciated :)

---

```
sdkVersion:'8'
targetSdkVersion:'15'
uses-permission:'com.livetrekker.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.CAMERA'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION'
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.VIBRATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.GET_TASKS'
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_LOGS'
uses-permission:'android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS'
uses-permission:'android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS'
uses-permission:'android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS'
uses-permission:'com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.camera'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.camera.front'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.camera.flash'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.camera.autofocus'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.sensor.compass'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.location'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.location.network'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.location.gps'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.microphone'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.wifi'
uses-gl-es:'0x20000'
```

Comment: Does your app really needs all these permissions??

Comment: Hello guys, thanks for the answers. Yes, we need lots of permissions, the app is quite complex. Although by re-reading them, some may not be needed anymore :) -- I don't think it is a Copy Protect issue, because this is related to the Google Play processes (right?), and the app was refused by a Chinese Android market.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay we found out why, turned out it was the compass feature that was not available on those devices. So setting it as required:false should do the trick.

Comment: So how did you figure it out? I have the same problem now trying to understand why Chromebooks are 'unsupported' by my app.

Comment: Why did not you mark CRUSADER's answer as right answer.

Answer (score 4):

That's because some phone may or may not have some features that you have defined essential..

like for example:- `android.hardware.camera.front`

So try adding like this...,

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
```

Check out this [link for clarity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#market-feature-filtering)

Comment: Hi, we already did this, and I checked the doc, my question was more about getting more info from the Google Play interface. Because if they can filter, why can't we get as a log the filtering details :(